# Orphans remain in database even with orphanRemoval=true on one-to-many relationship (JPA/Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa-2.0, orphan

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name = "company_policies")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "rule_name")
public abstract class AbstractPolicyRule implements Serializable {

  @Transient
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  private String value;

  ...
}
```

_

```
@Entity
public class Category implements Serializable {

  @Transient
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  @Column(name = "category_name")
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name = "category_policy_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  private Set<AbstractPolicyRule> activePolicyRules;

  ...
}
```

When this Set is updated the existing activePolicyRules have their category_policy_id set to null in the database and new ones are inserted.  I'd like for the original ones to be deleted.

I thought adding the orphanRemoval = true would do that but it's not.  Other questions I've seen on this appear to have bi-directional relationships and setting the parent to null solves it, but this is not a bi-directional relationship.

Any suggestions?

Using Hibernate 3.5.3

Edit:
This only happens when an existing AbstractPolicyRule exists in the database, I remove it from the list and then save the Category again.  It's foreign key, category_policy_id, is set to null instead of being deleted.

```
[DEBUG] Collection found: [domain.category.Category.activePolicyRules#1], was: 
[<unreferenced>] (initialized)
[DEBUG] Flushed: 0 insertions, 2 updates, 0 deletions to 2 objects
[DEBUG] Flushed: 1 (re)creations, 0 updates, 1 removals to 1 collections
...
[DEBUG] Deleting collection: [domain.category.Category2.activePolicyRules#1]
[DEBUG] about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
[DEBUG] update company_policies set category_policy_id=null where category_policy_id=?
[DEBUG] done deleting collection
```

Also tried a join table since the Hibernate documentation discourages the previous way:

```
@Entity
public class Category implements Serializable {

  @Transient
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  @Column(name = "category_name")
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinTable(name = "policy_rule_mapping", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "rule_id"))
  private Set<AbstractPolicyRule> activePolicyRules;

  ...
}
```

This has the same issue.  The row in the mapping table is deleted but the AbstractPolicyRule still contains the removed item.

Comment: The scenario I tested was actually very close to your edit. I changed my test to remove the existing element from the collection without adding another one and it still gets deleted. Note that I'm not using any inheritance though (I think that you might be).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm using `orphanRemoval=true` with an unidirectional One-to-Many association without any problem.

And actually, I tested your code and the following scenario (`AbstractPolicyRule` implementing `equals`/`hashCode` correctly):

```
Category category = new Category();
AbstractPolicyRule policyRule1 = new AbstractPolicyRule("foo");

category.addToActivePolicyRules(policyRule1);
em.persist(category);
em.flush();

assertNotNull(category.getId());
assertNotNull(category.getActivePolicyRules());
assertEquals(1, category.getActivePolicyRules().size());

category.removeFromActivePolicyRules(policyRule1);
category.addToActivePolicyRules(new AbstractPolicyRule("bar"));
// category = em.merge(category); // works with or without
em.flush();
assertEquals(1, category.getActivePolicyRules().size());
```

just works as expected. Below the generated traces:

```
22:54:30.817 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into Category (id, category_name) values (null, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Category (id, category_name) values (null, ?)
22:54:30.824 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.StringType - binding null to parameter: 1
22:54:30.844 [main] DEBUG o.h.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper - Natively generated identity: 1
...
22:54:30.872 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into AbstractPolicyRule (id, name) values (null, ?)
Hibernate: insert into AbstractPolicyRule (id, name) values (null, ?)
22:54:30.873 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.StringType - binding 'foo' to parameter: 1
22:54:30.874 [main] DEBUG o.h.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper - Natively generated identity: 1
...
22:54:30.924 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - update AbstractPolicyRule set category_policy_id=? where id=?
Hibernate: update AbstractPolicyRule set category_policy_id=? where id=?
22:54:30.927 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.LongType - binding '1' to parameter: 1
22:54:30.928 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.LongType - binding '1' to parameter: 2
22:54:30.929 [main] DEBUG o.h.p.c.AbstractCollectionPersister - done inserting collection: 1 rows inserted
22:54:30.929 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - Executing batch size: 1
...
22:54:30.945 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into AbstractPolicyRule (id, name) values (null, ?)
Hibernate: insert into AbstractPolicyRule (id, name) values (null, ?)
22:54:30.948 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.StringType - binding 'bar' to parameter: 1
22:54:30.948 [main] DEBUG o.h.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper - Natively generated identity: 2
...
22:54:30.990 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - update AbstractPolicyRule set category_policy_id=null where category_policy_id=? and id=?
Hibernate: update AbstractPolicyRule set category_policy_id=null where category_policy_id=? and id=?
22:54:30.991 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.LongType - binding '1' to parameter: 1
22:54:30.992 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.LongType - binding '1' to parameter: 2
22:54:30.993 [main] DEBUG o.h.p.c.AbstractCollectionPersister - done deleting collection rows: 1 deleted
22:54:30.993 [main] DEBUG o.h.p.c.AbstractCollectionPersister - Inserting rows of collection: [com.stackoverflow.q3304092.Category.activePolicyRules#1]
22:54:30.994 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - Executing batch size: 1
...
22:54:30.996 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - update AbstractPolicyRule set category_policy_id=? where id=?
Hibernate: update AbstractPolicyRule set category_policy_id=? where id=?
22:54:30.997 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.LongType - binding '1' to parameter: 1
22:54:30.998 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.LongType - binding '2' to parameter: 2
22:54:31.002 [main] DEBUG o.h.p.c.AbstractCollectionPersister - done inserting rows: 1 inserted
...
22:54:31.015 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - delete from AbstractPolicyRule where id=?
Hibernate: delete from AbstractPolicyRule where id=?
22:54:31.017 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.LongType - binding '1' to parameter: 1
```

The first policy rule gets deleted.

If this is not representative of what you're doing, you should maybe provide more code.

**Update:** Answering a comment from the OP...

> Wow I just changed the saveOrUpdate call to merge and now it's removing appropriately. You have any insight why that is?

Just a guess: since `orphanRemoval` is a JPA thing, I wonder if `saveOrUpdate` will deal appropriately with it (actually, I thought you were using the `EntityManager` API since you mentioned JPA).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I've updated my post with more info that hopefully makes sense.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what "set equals/hash code correctly" means.  Right now the equals/hash code is using the unique identifiers for the table (but not the id).

Comment: @Josh That's a good implementation (and I used such an implementation above when trying to reproduce the problem).

Comment: One thing I just noticed was that you are using persist and I'm using saveOrUpdate.  I'll try persist and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Wow I just changed the saveOrUpdate call to merge and now it's removing appropriately.  You have any insight why that is?

Comment: @Josh: I used persist to populate test data. Then, I just let JPA detect the changes (but also tested merge) and things were working appropriately. I've update my answer to cover your comment.

Comment: Thanks Pascal, your answers helped push me in the right direction.  I've been looking at why one would use merge vs. saveOrUpdate and haven't found any clear answers why merge removed the orphans and saveOrUpdate didn't in my particular case but it appears to be working.  Thanks again.

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue with Hibernate 4.3.5 and orphanRemoval with a `@OneToMany` mapping, but I cannot seem to get it to work.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/24579374/827480.

Comment: @Josh The merge() in stead of saveOrUpdate() did the trick for me as well. The difference in semantics between pure Hibernate and JPA seems to be important (and I neglected this).

Answer (score 4):

First make sure your classes implement the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods, so that hibernate knows that exactly these items are removed from the set.

Then try defining the hibernate `@Cascade` annotation, specifying the delete-orphan cascade type there and observer whether the same happens. If it works the way you want it - report a bug in hibernate and temporarily use the proprietary annotation. Otherwise - update the question with the details