# How to delete records in all tables when using @JoinTable (with Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, mapping

I have a class called `News`. Any news can have many `Photo`. These are my table

```
   news                   news_photo             photo
--------------      ----------------------     ------------
| id | title |      | id_news | id_photo |     | id | url |
--------------      ----------------------     ------------
  |                      |         |              |
  |----------------------|         |--------------|
```

This is my class `News`

```
@Entity    
@Table(name = "news")
public class News extends ElementoPersistente implements Serializable{  
    ...
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "news_photo",
               joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_news")},
               inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_photo") }) 
    private List<photo> photos;
    ...
}
```

When I remove an object from `List<photo> photos` and then I save the object `News`, the relative record is deleted from the table `news_photo` but nothing is deleted inside the table `photo`.
How can I delete both records inside `news_photo` and `photo`?

Thank you

Comment: I have been digging through some documentation and just noticed your `orphanRemoval = true` on the owner. Do you have the SQL logging turned on when perform the flush operation on the `EntityManager`?

Comment: Also, what is the JPA provider you're using?

Comment: Also, there might be another relationship on photo which you are forgetting about and which stops the deletion of that element from the DB. Or even triggers might do it on the DB side.

Comment: Im using Hibernate and I have nothing else on Photo. I even deleted foreign keys.

Comment: Do you have the SQL shown with <property name="show_sql">true</property> to see what hibernate is doing in the background?

Comment: by any chance did you check the database to see what happens with the photo and whether is has left more joins on the `news_photo` table?

Comment: Have a look at this post. [Orphans remain in database even with orphanRemoval=true on one-to-many relationship (JPA/Hibernate)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304092/orphans-remain-in-database-even-with-orphanremoval-true-on-one-to-many-relations?rq=1)

Comment: also, you can check my code at https://github.com/joaorebelo-ar/so-36648055

Comment: @JoãoRebelo thank for you help. I read the first link, but it doesn't solve my problem ( I even tried to use merge instea of update).
I read your code and it's very similar to mine. Are you sure that 'childs' are deleted in their table when a Child is removed from Parent.children list?

Comment: well without having a look at the code I am unable to help anymore. Have you tried my example in your machine? Somehow it seems the hibernate engine figures there is still a reference to that `photo` in your DB. I see that you're extending `ElementoPersistente`.

Comment: Are you using the JPA calls (e.g. `merge`, `persist`, etc.) or the Hibernate calls (e.g. `saveOrUpdate`)?  For whatever reason this seems to have made a difference in some other scenarios.